# Parsing JSON string with Chinese character

Tags: vb.net, json.net

The are various question similar to my problem I have found on SO but none of them are able to solve the issue I am having. I have been provided a text file which contains the following string,

```
callback12({  
"searchResult":{  
  "data":[  
     {  
        "CURRENCY":"人民币",
        "DATE":"2016-03-25",
        "NAME":"仲尧文"
     },
     {  
        "CURRENCY_TYPE":"人民币",
        "DATE":"2016-03-24",
        "NAME":"王新华"
     }]
}
  })
```

I am using following line of code to parse the JSON string,

```
Dim objTempResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(strSource)
Dim objResults = objTempResults("callback12")("searchResult")("data").Children()
```

But it is giving me the exception on JObject.Parse that,

```
Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: \. Path '', line 0, position 0.
```

The other questions that I have found have answers to encode and decode the string but I cannot encode or decode the whole string as there are only two fields which needs to be encoded. How can I solve this exception?

Comment: Your text is probably destroyed by whatever `String2Unicode` is. VB.NET uses Unicode directly, there is no need in that.

Comment: The example you have given is not valid JSON.  In particular, the `(` after `callback12` has no valid meaning in JSON.

Comment: @GSerg I have removed the String2Unicode function. It was just one of different ways I am trying.

Comment: @user5090812 The JSON is valid. I just removed couple of extra fields but forgot to remove the extra comma after "Name" field. I have now removed the comma and the JSON is valid now.

Comment: Thing that is inside `callback12()` may be valid JSON. The entire thing is however not [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/).

Comment: @GSerg I have just verified and validated the JSON along with callback12() and it was validated as valid RFC 4627 JSON string. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Please do not use crappy validators. Try a [better one](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: @GSerg OK you are right. I am no expert of JSON nested format and I validated the JSON with the link that I have posted in above comment. After your comment when I have removed the callback() from the string then it was parsed without problem. I know that it was a format issue and was minor but if someone just could point it out as an answer then I will mark it as acceptable answer.

Comment: @GSerg Now I know that there are crappy validators too.

Comment: Correction "Now know that there are crappy validators too".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Chinese characters in the JSON are not the problem here.  You are getting a parse error because your JSON is wrapped inside a javascript function call, which makes it invalid JSON.  (See [JSON.org](http://json.org/) for details on what is considered valid JSON syntax.)  If you remove the `callback12()` surrounding the JSON, it will parse correctly with Json.Net.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xN5JJi

Comment: Thank you for posting this as an answer. I was hoping that "GSerg" who pointed this out earlier will be able to get the credit but thanks to you too. Cheers